# fatal error: google fonts in flutter throws error

Tags: flutter, google-fonts

i'm getting this error in flutter

```
../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_fonts-2.3.0/lib/google_fonts.dart:142265:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'displayLarge'.
      displayLarge:
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart:81:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const TextTheme({
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

while running mobile application

some code snippets...

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.4
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts:
  get:
```

**code**

```
     Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Details',
                style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(),
              ),
            )
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you try with `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app.

Comment: i have already tried that , but it seems like issue  is with library & flutter version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try setting a specific version as it seems to be caused by a requirement by the recent google_fonts update.

Using `google_fonts:2.1.1` worked for me.

Also check https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/issues/219 .

Comment: yes i have updated version & it works

Comment: Above solution worked perfectly. I am just extending that set dependency version `google_fonts:2.2.0` and don't forgot to remove `^` sign

Answer (score 1):

i have updated flutter version to 2.10.0 & now it is working